# Reorder items in Reminders app

Tags: ios, reminders

Can't find a way to reorder tasks in Reminders. Am I missing something or it really is not possible?

Update: Apple added this feature to iOS 6.

Comment: Has anyone worked out how to re-order lists in the Reminders Web App at icloud.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no method to change the order of reminders. Neither priority nor due date of a reminder has an influence on the position in the list.

Comment: Let's hope they update it soon, really love this app except for this missing feature.

Comment: It is a bit confusing, as Apple states 'Make a list: Reminders appear in a clean, ordered list.' on their page about iOS 5.0's new features (http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html#reminders)

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out how to re-order reminders. The secret is to click on a list item to the right of the text. In other words, if the item reads, "Pick up dry cleaning", click in the empty area to the right of the word "cleaning". This will cause the entire item to turn slightly darker, as if highlighted. Then, just click it and drag it up or down to the desired location.

The secret is in where you click. If you click on the text, you'll get a cursor, enabling you to edit the entry. Click out to the right, however, and you can highlight the item for dragging.

Comment: Are you on iOS 5 or 6?

Comment: IOS 5.1.1, but I have a confession to make. In my tip to rearrange list items, I was referring to the desktop app in Mountain Lion (and that does work). I just tried it on my iPad, though, and it doesn't work. To make matters worse, the new list arrangement does not seem to be synching to the iPad, so the same list is ordered differently on the two devices.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done!  On an iPhone 7, I tap on the item and hold for about one second.  The background darkens and then I'm free to move the item up or down the list.

Answer (score 1):

On MacBook I have ordered my Reminders by selecting Title as the order of sorting (under 'View'), and prefixing each item with a 2-digit sequential number, to act as the sort key.  If you wish to insert an item between two that you have already numbered, you can simply add another digit to the sort number of that item, as in the Dewey Decimal system used in libraries. E.G. If you already have '01 See to animals', '02 Put out bins' and you want to add 'Put on washing' between those two, give it the number '011'

Answer (score 0):

The only work around that I have found is to drag your reminder to another list, then bring it back to the list you want it in. It will bring that reminder to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Click edit and then touch the 3 lined icon on the right hand side of the reminder item, and you can move it up and down!

Answer (score 0):

click the task on the list your want to move. when it highlighted, you can move it up and down.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reorder tasks on my iPhone 5S, either. However, in the iCloud desktop (WIN7),there is a category that doesn't appear on my 5S. It's called "Scheduled." That is where you will find tasks in day and time order, scheduled automatically by the app. The tasks, et all, you store in the categories that you set up on your phone, pad, or computer can be highlighted, but not moved. Rather, you can move them, but they won't stay!

Answer (score 0):

Using the main list on the computer select for each list: View, Sort By, Manual. Drag them manually into the correct order and this will then be duplicated in your other devices. The previous comment about dragging your reminder to another list may help too but I haven't tried it. Making the new list Manual before importing may also help.

Comment: This does not work for me on a shared list, the order I drag the items to in Reminders on OSX Mavericks, is not at all reflected on the other party's list on either an iOS9 iPhone SE, or a desktop running Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Edit. Press and hold the lines on right of item to be moved. Slowly drag the item left then right until the grey circle/slash disappears, then drag the item to new position and let go.