# How to move existing reminders to iCloud in the reminder app?

Tags: ios, icloud, reminders

There is already a question on [reordering of items](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29910/reorder-items-in-reminders-app) in the reminder app, but I want to go one step further and move existing items from the device to iCloud. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Tap the item
2. Select "Show more..."
3. Tap "List"
4. Select the list where to move the item.

Comment: That seems new. Nice feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can't seem to drag lists down to iCloud, nor can you seem to drag an item(s) from one list to another - but you can move items using the context menu

Create duplicate lists in the iCloud section of the list of lists...(you can probably see one called 'reminders' there already)

Go back to the list you want to move highlight all items in the list (not the text in one item but the item itself) - then bring up the context menu and select move... chose your duplicated list as destination

You may also wan to move the completed items from the old list itself to the new click on the 'completed' at the top of the list

Comment: I can't quite follow you. How do you bring up the context menu...?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings > iCloud** (Alternatively, Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > iCloud) and make sure Reminders syncing is on.

Answer (score 0):

Select the item

A blue circled i will appear on the right

Select the i

The context  menu will appear

List of the second last item

select the list name and the other list names will appear

select the new list name from the list

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the Export and Import options from the File menu. Export from one list and import to another - worked for me on Sierra.