# Any way to make shared reminders lists be in the same order?

Tags: reminders

I'm on Mavericks.  I have shared a list in Reminders with someone, and have put in a lot of effort to make sure the list is in a specific order.  Just now she opened the list up on her iOS9 phone and the order is completely scrambled.  She also checked the list on her Mavericks machine and it's in a completely different, but also scrambled order.

What's going on here?  Do shared reminders created on one machine, have no bearing at all on the order of the list on the other party's device(s)?  Do the other devices just shuffle the items into a completely random order?  Is there any way to ensure that a list I order a specific way on my side, reflects the same order on the other party's side?

EDIT:  Apparently [this has been an issue at least back to 2012](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4180396?start=0&tstart=0)...

Comment: How did you order them? Alphabetical, by date due, other?

Comment: No special order for entry, I moved them around after I typed the items in, to place them in the required order.

Comment: Interesting q&a here. [Reorder items in Reminders App](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/29910/120171)

Comment: Unfortunately that discussion appears to be around non-shared lists.  The one person who described what is effectively my situation, provided a solution that doesn't work for me (my list was already in manual sort order, and the order is still different and all messed up on both of the other party's different devices).  Not sure if this is exclusively a problem for shared lists or not, but that's the one big difference in my case.

Comment: I’m wondering if a shared note in the notes app would do better.  No reminder with it though. :/

Comment: Yeah I don't actually need reminders, I just liked the ability to rearrange items easily in a Reminders list.  With Notes each item is just a string of text rather than an object that can be moved around independently.  But yeah you may be right, if order is critical (which it is here), then Notes might end up being the answer.  I'll experiment.

Comment: For crying out loud... apparently you can't do shared notes in OSX Mavericks.  I had no idea... thought for sure you could.  Guess that solution is out.  This really sucks... nobody has any idea how the sort order works in shared reminders??